# Can anyone explain this condensation pattern?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, phase, identification, electrostatic-energy

What is the hair-like polymer that condenses on the caps of the plastic cell vial? Inside vial are cells in a mixture of [FBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetal_bovine_serum) and [DMSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimethyl_sulfoxide). The vials were frozen slowly in a special isopropanol-filled container (isopropanol does not touch the vials) to $\pu{-80^\circ C}$, then put on dry ice to move to a liquid nitrogen cryogenic freezer.

The hair-like crystals appear to be water, but bend toward my finger when nearby, similar to static attraction. I suspect that it has something to do with DMSO/isopropanol leaking out, and the very low temperatures that cause this strange condensation pattern, but I'm not sure. [image: The hair like ice-crystals bend toward your finger, and melt when actually touched]

Comment: Those strains might also be DMSO or DMSO-water-isopropanol mixture. If you could determine the melting point more precisely, it would be easier to answer. Also, assuming you work in a decent lab, maybe do some HPLC analysis in a spare time to be 100% sure what that is.

Comment: @andselisk Thank you for your response. I was planning on doing an LCMS/HPLC on it sometime to be sure. Just wondering if anyone knew off the top of their heads :)